# Add sub-menus to a menu on action bar at runtime

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

In my application, I have a screen which has a menu on action bar on tap of which I show sub-menus which I need to put at runtime depending on the status of a process running in background.

e.g. Suppose, I am on screen SCREEN and my menu is MENU which has three sub-menus

```
MENU---->  1. SubMenu1
           2. SubMenu2
           3. SubMenu3
```

If a process PROCESS running in background is finished I want to display menus SubMenu1 and Submenu2 otherwise I'll put only SubMenu3 excluding SubMenu1 & SubMenu2.

I can take this decision in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` method but if the user is on the SCREEN and the PROCESS completes, SubMenu3 should be shown instead of the previously shown SubMenus.

I believe this can be done (as Play Store app adds "My Apps" menu at runtime).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` and create the options menu there based on the current state.

Whenever that state changes you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to indicate that the options menu needs to be recreated. This will recreate the menu and again call `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` as described in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29